# Traversing though list in list python

Tags: python

I have to see if M is in the list and if not append to list value is on the

```
list1 = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F", "G", "H"], ["I", "J", "K", "L"]]
```

I have tried:

```
def check_if_in_list(t):
    for items in list1:
        if t in list1:
            Print("True")
        else:
            Print("False")
            list1.append(t)

check_if_in_list("M")
```

It is not indexing properly through the list

Comment: The second line in the function should be `if t in items`, not `if t in List1`.

Comment: It looks like `check_if_in_list` is not iterating over *each list* that is contained within `list1`. In the code provided, `items` would be the list to search... as John G. mentioned in a comment -- `items` appears to be missing from the `if ... in` checks.

Comment: Further on @JohnGordon 's point `list1.append()` might possibly be `items.append()` though it is unsure if you are trying to add an M to each individual list or only once to the outer list.

Comment: where do you wanna put the 'M' though? you could also use the extend method to convert the lnested list into a single list with all elements if you don't need nested lists

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F", "G", "H"], ["I", "J", "K", "L"]]
def check_if_in_list(t):
    for items in list1:
        if t in items:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
            items.append(t)

check_if_in_list("M")
False
False
False
list1
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'M'],
 ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'M'],
 ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']]
```